# Lost on how to go about this

Tags: c++, loops

I am currently in CS135 and I am stuck on my assignment. It ask of me to do any type of loop but I have to "pay the customer per month one cent". And every month payment doubles. Then give an output of the 64 months,the total amount paid, and the amount paid up to the given month. I am at a complete loss. I got how to double the amount but from there on out I have no idea how to continue.
How do I effectively go about my assignment? (The prize is paid in the following manner: the winner receives one cent the day of the drawing. That amount is doubled for the next 64 months, e.g., month 2 the amount is two cents, month 3 the amount is four cents, and so on. Alternatively, the winner may choose to
take a lump-sum payment of $1,000,000.00.Write a C++ program that displays how much Mega Magazine Mart must pay the winner each month and the total paid as of each month. Identify with ** the month the company has paid a total of $1,000,000.00.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    for (int n = 1 ; n <= 65; n*= 2){
        cout << n << endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Why is "can someone help me" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Looking for a question mark... nope, no question here.

Comment: @JustinRandall Question mark added.

Comment: "I am currently in CS135..." Dude we're not breaking you out of a prison.

Comment: Thank you, thank you. I'm here all week. But seriously folks, when you encounter a problem you don't know how to solve, break it down into smaller pieces until they hit a size that you do know how to solve all of the pieces.

Comment: @user4581301 Okay and your point is? I was just stuck with something simple that I figured out with the help of LC-Data one piece of code helped me realize how stupid I have been. Thanks for your comments as useful as they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a variable, x, in your function and add the value of n(your payment every month?) to it each time it loops. At the end of the loop, this x variable will be the total amount paid.

At any given iteration of the loop, the current value of x will be the "amount paid up to the given month". You can print your x value during each loop to show this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    long double totalPayment = 0;
    long double currentPayment = 1;

    for (int n = 1 ; n <= 64; n++){
        totalPayment = totalPayment + currentPayment;

        cout << n << endl;          //This is the month
        cout << currentPayment << endl;         //This is the payment for the given month
        cout << totalPayment << endl;       //This is the total amount paid up to and including the given month

        currentPayment = currentPayment*2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Something like the above code.

Comment: @LC_Data Thanks for the reply, so main problem to this assignment is the output has to look something like this.

Comment: Month Amount Owed Total Paid
----- --------------------- ---------------------
 1          0.01 0.01
 2          0.02 0.03
 3           0.04 0.07
                  . . .
                 . . . **
 . . .
 64 . .
$

Comment: Hey dst, I updated my answer. It is basically the meat of your assignment, all that is left for you to do is figure out how to convert the payment in to dollars, as by the time you reach the 64th month the payout in cents becomes massive and is output as a scientific calculator would.

Secondly you need to figure out the formatting :) Hope it helped. Mark the answer as accepted if you liked it.

Comment: Thank you so much you helped me without completely giving me the answer to my assignment. That was wonderful! Now I can go to sleep without a worry.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take the power of 2 in each iteration. Also int might result in integer overflow. Hence the unsigned long.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    unsigned long  amt=1, total_amt=0, temp;

    for (int n = 0 ; n < 64; n++)
    { 
        temp = amt*pow(2,n);

        total_amt += temp; 
        cout << "current amount in month "<< n<<" " << temp << endl; 

    }

    cout << "total amount " << total_amt << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your monthly total due starts at 0.01 cents but double each month so over the 64 month period you owe a ridiculous amount. Just create a for loop over the duration and compute the monthly amount due as well as the accumulated total you've paid.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

double getPayment(double payment)
{
    return (payment == 0.0) ? payment += 0.01 : payment * 2.0;
}

int main()
{
    double amount{0.0};  // monthly payment amount
    double total{0.0};   // total paid over lifetime (64 months)
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpoint;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2); // money format i.e. $X.00
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        amount = getPayment(amount);
        total += amount;
        std::cout << "month["<<i+1<<"]: amount due "<< amount
           << ", total paid " << total << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Love your code but I have to give it to LC-Data all I need was the processing part of the code. Even though you gave me the answer completely I was not really looking for that. Thank you anyways Justin (P.S 135 we are still only in main function we are not making our own classes yet)

Comment: @dstaticnum thanks for the feedback I'm glad you got the processing part squared away. I'll concede defeat to LC-Data. If you found my answer useful please consider an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
int calculate(totalMonths){
int currAmount=1;
int totalAmount=0;
for(int currMonth=1; currMonth<=totalMonths; currMonth++){
    totalAmount = totalAmount+currAmount;
    currAmount *=2;
    cout<<"current month = "<<currMonth<<endl;
    cout<<"current amount = "<<currAmount<<endl;
    cout<<"total amount = "<<totalAmount<<endl;
}
```

}